# read public http csv data into Apache Beam

Tags: python, pandas, csv, apache-beam

I'm trying to use `apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_csv` function to read an online source with no success. Everything works if the file is hosted on google storage `'gs://bucket/source.csv'` but fails on getting the file from `'https://github.com/../source.csv'` like sources..

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

url  = 'https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/raw/main/files/people/people-100.csv'

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    original_collection = pipeline | read_csv(path=url)
    original_collection = original_collection[:5]
    original_collection | beam.Map(print)
```

Giving me

```
ValueError: Unable to get filesystem from specified path, please use the correct path or ensure the required dependency is installed, e.g., pip install apache-beam[gcp]. Path specified: https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/raw/main/files/people/people-100.csv
```

Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beam can only read files from filesystems (like gcs, hdfs, etc.) not arbitrary URLs (which are difficult to parallelize reads from). Local files work as well on the direct runner.

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
def parse_csv(contents):
  [use pandas, the csv module, etc. to parse the contents string into rows]

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    urls = pipeline | beam.Create(['https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/...'])
    contents = urls | beam.Map(lambda url: urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
    rows = contents | beam.FlatMap(parse_csv)
```

Probably easier to just save the file to a proper filesystem and read that...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to load an external file on `Beam`.

You can think about another process or service than `Beam` that copies your external files to `Cloud Storage` bucket (for example with `gsutil cp`).

Then in your `Dataflow` job, you could read files from `GCS` without issues.